# What is all the known information contained in thermal noise?

Tags: electricity, information, noise

I've read up a little bit on [thermal noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise), which is an unavoidable noise in materials when $T>0K$. Thanks to this noise, by measuring the voltage across a material, it is possible to extract the value of its resistance. Hence this noise contains at least the resistance of the material. And if the resistance is known, one can extract the value of the temperature, so the temperature information is also contained in this noise. But it also said that [the noise contains much more information](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.06858):

> By measuring higher correlators of noise  (e.g., averages of higher
>   powers of V) or by measuring the noise in a nonequilibrium regime, one
>   can avoid restrictions imposed by the fluctuation-dissipation theorem
>   and obtain the most detailed description of electron interactions.

I am interested in knowing everything that is currently known to be contained in such a noise. Could someone build up such a list?